# NSURLConnectionDelegate connection:didFailWithError: when will this be called?

Tags: php, ios, json, delegates, nsurlconnection

I am creating that uses `NSURLConnection` to retrieve a `JSON` formatted string from a webpage which will later be parsed to show information. I have implemented the `NSURLConnectionDelegate`, and i wanted to know if `didFailWithError` will capture an incident when the webpage didnt finish loading?

As an example, suppose the connection is started and connects to my php page and the php starts echo-ing out the `json` string but it server fails and only part of the string was posted? If `connection:didFailWithError`: didnt get fired, then an imcomplete json would cause my app to crash, so does `connection:didFailWithError`: handle this also??

Comment: Yes it will fire. Timeouts are the most common reason IMHO.

Comment: I don't think you can receive just a pice of JSON, you will receive a JSON or you don't, but the `didFail` method will be called if something will happend with the connection (timeout, no internet connection, server errors etc)

Comment: thanks! so i assume connectionDidFinishLoading:connection gets executed iff the connection was a success?

Comment: The delegate may also receive one or more of chunks of the body data in `connection:didReceiveData:` before the delegate will receive `connection:didFailWithError:`.